# Ansible permission issue

Tags: python, ansible

I have a simple ansible task that creates a file:

```
- name: create fake file 
  file:
    name: /opt/refdata/PROD02/roman.delete
    state: touch
```

I generated the public/private keys and added public one to authorized_keys2 for the user I am running as on the target host.

When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
failed: [experiment01] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acplus_uat01/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441921944.69-3869708445827/file", line 1999, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/acplus_uat01/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441921944.69-3869708445827/file", line 372, in main
    open(path, 'w').close()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/refdata/PROD02/roman.delete'
```

So, to see if I have issues with ssh or python I tried this - I created a python file with one line:

```
open('/opt/refdata/PROD02/roman.delete', 'w').close()
```

and ran this from the same place and the same user as I run ansible:

```
cat test2.py | ssh -i ~/.ssh/myPrivateKey -q target_user@targethost python -
```

and it created the file.

So, my question is - where is the problem, why can't it create a file?

the way I run the playbook is this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/prod/ acc.yml -v --vault-password-file=~/.ansible-vault-pw --private-key ~/.ssh/myPrivateKey
```

I also tried to create a file in /tmp/ and ansible worked.

Edit: So, another update - I made the directory I am writing the file into world writable ( 777 ) and it created the file. So, the question is - what is different in Ansible that

```
 cat test2.py | ssh -i ~/.ssh/myPrivateKey -q target_user@targethost python -
```

works and doing essentially the same thing through Ansible doesn't.

Comment: Since the ansible playbook can write files in /tmp but not here, I'd add a step to the play to `debug: var=ansible_ssh_user` and check that matches the user that your python script's being run by.

Comment: I'd simply touch /tmp/foo from within Ansible then look at the permissions & ownership of /tmp/foo afterwards to verify that the file is being created by Ansible with the attributes that you expect.

Comment: It is created with attributes that I expect - right user/group

Comment: @RomanGoyenko, is `/opt/refdata/PROD02/` an NFS volume ? Do you run the playbook with `sudo:yes` ? Do you have `nosuid` flag set on the PROD2  ( in case it a separate mount ) ? If one of those true, I can explain the behaviour ...

Comment: Have you tried running the playbook using "-vvvv"?

Comment: Does /opt/refdata/PROD02/ exist? If it doesn't then you should create directory first `file name=/opt/refdata/PROD02 state=directory recurse=yes`

Comment: /opt/refdata/PROD02/ exists and has the right user and group assigned

Comment: @Gregory Shulov: /dev/mapper/appvg1-applv1 on /opt/refdata type ext4 (rw)
this is the ext4 mount.

Answer (score 3):

If `/opt/refdata/PROD02/` doesn't exist you should create directory first

```
file:
  name: /opt/refdata/PROD02
  state: directory
  recurse: yes
  mode: 0755
```

[Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) says:

> **recurse** - Set the specified file attributes (**applies only to state=directory**)

So Ansible cannot create file and all the directories in it's path at one command.

Then with second command you should create the file itself.

```
name: create fake file 
  file:
    name: /opt/refdata/PROD02/roman.delete
    state: touch
```

Comment: /opt/refdata/PROD02/ does exist